# Magento2: How to add an orange border on the search engine

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add orange border in search engine.

https://zabezcen.pl/

Here is style.css file for reference:

```
      .searchbox-header {
            .search-wrapper {

                .block-content {
                    position: relative;

                    .nested {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    .input-text {
                        height: 44px;
                        border: none;
                        padding-right: 40px;
                        color: #444;
                        font-size: 108.33%;
                        .border_radius(3px);
                    }

                    .btn-search-header {
                        position: absolute;
                        right: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        width: 34px;
                        height: 34px;
                        opacity: 1;
                        padding: 0 !important;
                        background: transparent;
                        text-align: center;

                        &:hover {
                            color: #444 !important;
                        }

                        &:before {
                            .font-awesome(f002, 14px);
                            line-height: 34px;
                        }

                        span {
                            display: none;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // SEARCH BOX PRO

        .sm-searchbox {
            .sm-searchbox-content {
                position: relative;

                .control {
                    .searchbox-cat {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        background-color: #fafafa;
                        border: none;
                        height: 44px;
                        width: 170px;
                        color: #444;
                        padding-left: 15px;
                        font-size: 108.33%;
                        border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
                        .border_radius(3px 0 0 3px);

                        &:hover {
                            cursor: pointer;
                        }
                    }

                    #searchbox {
                        padding-left: 190px;
                        height: 44px;
                        border: none;
                        color: #444;
                        padding-right: 40px;
                        font-size: 108.33%;
                        .border_radius(3px);
                    }
                }

                .actions {
                    .btn-searchbox {
                        height: 40px;
                        opacity: 1;
                        padding: 0 !important;
                        position: absolute;
                        right: 2px;
                        text-align: center;
                        top: 2px;
                        width: 40px;
                        .border_radius(3px);

                        &:before {
                            .font-awesome(f002, 18px);
                            line-height: 40px;
                        }

                        span {
                            display: none;
                        }

                        &:hover {
                            color: #333 !important;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // END SEARCH BOX PRO

    }
}
```

photo:
[image]

Comment: update border property to     border: 1px solid orange; then check

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. It will help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below CSS

```
#searchbox {
    padding-left: 190px;
    height: 44px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    color: #444;
    padding-right: 40px;
    font-size: 108.33%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Ok I will check and then accept your answear. Thank you.

Comment: can you please check this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263081/magento2-how-to-change-layout-product-detail  and try to little help us?