# Magento2: How to change layout product detail

Tags: magento2, template

I want to change size and layout product detail:

from:
[image]

similar to:

[image]

details.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
$_config  = $this->helper('Sm\Market\Helper\Data');
$tabStyle = $_config->getProductDetail('tab_style');

$show_custom_tab   = $_config->getProductDetail('show_custom_tab');
$custom_tab_name   = $_config->getProductDetail('custom_tab_name');
$customtab_content = $_config->getProductDetail('customtab_content');
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')): ?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items <?php echo $tabStyle . '-style' ?>" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php if ($tabStyle == "default" || $tabStyle == "vertical") { ?>
                <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
                        <?php
                        $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                        if (!trim($html)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                        $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                        ?>
                        <li class="data item title"
                            aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            $alias ?>-title"
                            data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $alias ?>">
                            <a class="data switch"
                               tabindex="-1"
                               data-toggle="switch"
                               href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                               $alias ?>"
                               id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                               $alias ?>-title">
                                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                $label ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php if ($show_custom_tab) { ?>
                        <li id="tab-label-customtab" class="data item title" aria-labeledby="tab-label-customtab-title" data-role="collapsible" role="tab" data-collapsible="true" aria-controls="product.info.customtab" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
                                <a class="data switch"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   data-toggle="switch"
                                   href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                   $alias ?>"
                                   id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                   $alias ?>-title">
                                    <?php echo $custom_tab_name ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>

                <div class="resp-tabs-container">
                    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
                        <?php
                        $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                        if (!trim($html)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                        $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                        ?>

                        <div class="data item content resp-tab-content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            $html ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php if ($show_custom_tab) { ?>
                        <div class="data item content resp-tab-content" id="customtab" data-role="content">
                                <?php
                                echo $customtab_content;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
                    <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                    ?>
                    <h2 class="data item title resp-accordion"
                        aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $alias ?>-title"
                        data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    $alias ?>">
                        <a class="data switch"
                           tabindex="-1"
                           data-toggle="switch"
                           href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           $alias ?>"
                           id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           $alias ?>-title">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            $label ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>

                    <div class="data item content resp-tab-content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $html ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php if ($show_custom_tab) { ?>
                    <h2 id="tab-label-customtab" class="data item title resp-accordion" aria-labeledby="tab-label-customtab-title" data-role="collapsible" role="tab" data-collapsible="true" aria-controls="product.info.customtab" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
                        <a class="data switch"
                           tabindex="-1"
                           data-toggle="switch"
                           href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           $alias ?>"
                           id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           $alias ?>-title">
                            <?php echo $custom_tab_name ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="data item content resp-tab-content" id="customtab" data-role="content">
                        <?php
                        echo $customtab_content;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>


        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

gallery.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product media data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
 */

$_config = $this->helper('Sm\Market\Helper\Data');

$zoom_enable = $_config->getProductDetail('use_zoom_image');
$zoom_width  = $_config->getProductDetail('zoom_width');

$thumbstyle    = $_config->getProductDetail('thumbs_style');
$loop          = $_config->getProductDetail('image_loop');
$keyboard      = $_config->getProductDetail('image_keyboard');
$bigNav        = $_config->getProductDetail('image_navigation');
$fullscreen    = $_config->getProductDetail('image_fullscreen');
$thumbs_width  = $_config->getProductDetail('thumbs_width');
$thumbs_height = $_config->getProductDetail('thumbs_height');
$thumbs_nav    = $_config->getProductDetail('thumbs_navigation');

$breakpoints = $_config->getProductDetail('breakpoints_width');


?>
<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <div data-role="loader" class="loading-mask">
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
                 alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                 echo __('Loading...') ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Fix for jumping content. Loader must be the same size as gallery.-->
<script>
    var config = {
            "width": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
            "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
            ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
            "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",
            "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height'); ?>
        },
        thumbBarHeight = 0,
        loader = document.querySelectorAll('[data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder"] [data-role="loader"]')[0];

    if (config.navtype === 'horizontal') {
        thumbBarHeight = config.thumbheight;
    }

    loader.style.paddingBottom = ( config.height / config.width * 100) + "%";
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": {
                    <?php if ($zoom_enable) { ?>
                        "enabled": true,
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        "enabled": false,
                    <?php } ?>

                    "fullscreenzoom":"20",
                    "top":"",
                    "left":"",
                    "height":"",

                    "eventType":"hover",
                    "width": <?php echo $zoom_width; ?>,
                    "mode": "outside"
                },
                "data": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>,
                "options": {
                    <?php if ($thumbstyle == 'horizontal' || $thumbstyle == 'vertical') { ?>
                        "nav": "thumbs",
                        "navdir": "<?php echo $thumbstyle; ?>",
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        "nav": "dots",
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ($loop) { ?>
                        "loop": true,
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        "loop": false,
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ($keyboard) { ?>
                        "keyboard": true,
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        "keyboard": false,
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ($bigNav) { ?>
                        "arrows": true,
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        "arrows": false,
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ($fullscreen) { ?>
                        "allowfullscreen": true,
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        "allowfullscreen": false,
                    <?php } ?>





                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/caption"))): ?>
                        "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    "width": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>",

                    <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width')): ?>
                        "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
            ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    "thumbwidth": "<?php echo $thumbs_width; ?>",
                    "thumbheight": "<?php echo $thumbs_height; ?>",

                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration")): ?>
                        "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect"); ?>",

                    <?php if ($thumbs_nav) { ?>
                        "navarrows": true,
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        "navarrows": false,
                    <?php } ?>

                    "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $block->getVar("gallery/navtype"); ?>",

                    "thumbmargin": <?php echo $_config->getProductDetail('thumbs_margin'); ?>,
                    "thumbborderwidth": <?php echo $_config->getProductDetail('thumbs_borderwidth'); ?>
                },

                "fullscreen": {
                    "nav": "thumbs",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop")): ?>
                        "loop": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "navdir": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir"); ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/navarrows")): ?>
                        "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navarrows"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "navtype": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navtype"); ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows")): ?>
                        "arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption")): ?>
                        "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration")): ?>
                        "transitionduration": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration"); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "transition": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect"); ?>"
                },

                "breakpoints":{
                    "mobile":{
                        "conditions":{
                            "max-width":"<?php echo $breakpoints . 'px' ?>"
                        },

                        "options":{
                            "options":{
                                "nav":"dots"
                            },

                            "magnifierOpts": {
                                "enabled": false
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

anyone help how to do?

Answer (score 2):

You should go through the Magento frontend dev guide. It will give you an idea to customize frontend layouts and Magento2 custom HTML container is the best option to customize the layout without making any changes to any template files.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html